# Backbone.js - Updating a View vs. rendering a new View

Tags: performance, backbone.js, backbone-views

I am building a webapp for the iPad and i am running in some performance issues lately. I have a list of news on the left and a single news view on the right. When you tap on a news, it shows the full news on the right.

At the moment i am generating a new view each time a news is tapped. Now my Views Template stays the same for each News and i am wondering if i would get better performance by just updating the View on the right side wit hthe selected News content, instead of generating a new View each time.

If so, is there a Backbone way of updating a View with a new Models data or just simple jQuery?

Comment: Interesting article in this area: http://ianstormtaylor.com/break-apart-your-backbonejs-render-methods/

Answer (score 1):

As far as performance goes and whether it pays to just update parts of it will probably depends on how complex your view is, and how much of it is changing.

That said you can have one view for your right side new item and then just swap it's model and `trigger` the `change event` or call a `refresh` method on the view. Something like

```
var NewsItemView = BackBone.View.extend({

   initialize: function() {
     this.model.bind('change', this.refresh, this);
   },

   refresh: function () {
     this.$el.find('#partIWantToUpdate').html(this.model.get('someField'));
   }
})
```

And then rather then create a new view you just swap it's model

```
newItemView.model = newsModel;
newsModel.trigger('change');
```

Or  just forget about binding to the change event and just call the method directly

```
newItemView.refresh();
```

Another option is you can create a view for each news item and cache that view in your collection's view and then every time an news item is tapped you `detach` (it's important that you `detach` instead of `remove` as removing will also remove any bound events) the current view from the `DOM`(well really the current view's `el`) and attach the newly selected model's view.

Answer (score 0):

Could be something as simple as:

```
// code no tested
var NewsView = Backbone.View.extend({
  changeCollection: function( collection ){
    this.collection = collection;
    this.render();
  }
});
```